# Can i insulate the extra space in the room

Tags: insulation

My house has one room that has an extra closet space but this is not insulated. The house has 2 stories and the top is triangular shaped so the rooms have that little bit of space behind the wall, we have a door and it's now being used as a storage space. Can I insulate it? I want to create a little space for my kids to play in (it is big enough to fit another bed and for adults to stand in). I live in Texas and I was reading that we shouldn't insulate the attic but this is not in the attic and I can't find any information on it on Google. Thank you

Comment: Attics usually need ventilation to keep the roof deck cooler.  The living space of a house(walls and top ceiling) should be insulated as much as possible.  As long as the attic ventilation is not blocked, usually found on the under side of the roof outside of top wall and roof peak, then can insulate the walls as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Insulating is the least of your concerns. Before you build out a space that will actively be occupied by people and furniture, you need to have someone qualified look at the flooring structure to make sure it's strong enough for that. An attic space that might be used for a little bit of static storage needs much less strength than a room of bouncing kids, walking adults and furniture.